# Passing value from database to view in DropDownList in ASP.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Controller and I am taking an object of database and passing it to view.
Here is the action method for it

```
public ActionResult NewRequest(Bookinfo bookinfo)
    {

        using (var db = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            return View(db.Bookinfoes.ToList());
        }

    }
```

And here is my view method

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Models.Bookinfo>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "NewRequest";
}

<h2>NewRequest</h2>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bookname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Authorname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publishername)
        </td>
  <td> </td>
  </tr>

 }
</table>
```

As you can see that I am able to display the data normally but i want to display the data in drop downlist. Also I want to select an item from dropdownlist and take its value so that i can manipulate it
How can I do it???
Sorry if this seems to be a simple question. i have just started learning asp.net mvc4

Here is the book info model

```
namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Bookinfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bookname { get; set; }
    public string Authorname { get; set; }
    public string Publishername { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Comment: Please post Bookinfo model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownList` helper will make your drop down list. All you have to do is to build your `SelectList` dropdownlist content. You can try this :

```
  // Remove foreach loop

  <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Bookname", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.BookName, Value = m.Bookname} ).ToList())
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DropDownList("Authorname", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.Authorname, Value = m.Authorname} ).ToList())
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DropDownList("Publishername", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.Publishername, Value = m.Publishername} ).ToList())
        </td>
  <td> </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: if i remove the foreach loop then how can i get item

Comment: now if i want to use the value that has been selected how can i do it ? Basically If a user selects a bookname and clicks a button then if the book has not been issued to someone then it should be issued to him. And if not then it should show the date the book will be free. If you can give the big picture that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In controller store the select list into View Bag:

```
ViewBag.BookinfoId = new SelectList(db.Bookinfoes, "BookinfoId", "BookinfoName");
```

And in your view Use the ViewBag Name to bind the dropdown :

```
@Html.DropDownList("BookinfoId", "Select")
```

Comment: I am getting an error 
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: try ViewBag.BookinfoId = new SelectList(db.Bookinfoes.ToList(), "BookinfoId", "BookinfoName");
As you are using "using" block. So the context is disposed before reaching the view.

Comment: ohkkk. I am sorry but as I am new to it ,  this thing still confuses me